# From the 1960s TV Show The Invaders: Carnivorous Moths?

Tags: episode-identification, the-invaders

I remember a scene where they feed these moths a pork chop of all things. It was as usual a way to take over the Earth. I may have the wrong show. I have searched for "carnivorous moths" and "the invaders" but only gotten hits about real-life carnivorous moths (creepy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you're thinking of the episode with carnivorous butterflies? [Season 1](http://www.theinvaders.tv/season1.htm), Episode 7, "Nightmare", has those (emphasis mine).

> Vincent finds himself in the small town of Grady, Kansas, investigating the case of Ellen Woods (Kathleen Widdoes), a local high school teacher who was recently attacked by a swarm of locusts after she saw "a box with dials and things that made a loud, whiny noise" in a local farmer's barn. At Ellen's boarding house, a couple of old biddies living across the hall from her room tell Vincent that Ellen has gone away, and soon after he is threatened by her boyfriend Ed Gidney (James Callahan). Vincent then makes his way to the house of Ellen's boss, the seemingly kindly school principal Oliver Ames (Robert Emhardt) who says that Ellen is now boarding with him to keep her from the limelight. Ellen appears and says that she will talk, and Vincent asks her some questions, but she gets very agitated, and Vincent is told by Ames to leave. Ed and two of his friends track Vincent down to the town diner and beat him unconscious. Shortly after this, Constable Ned Gabbard (William Bramley), who is the top cop in Grady, takes Vincent out of town, but before he can be left at the side of the road in the middle of nowhere, Vincent grabs the steering wheel, forces the car off the road and makes a run for it through a corn field. Ellen, who is reacting to the return of the locusts, instigated by Gabbard to take care of the escaping Vincent, flees from Ames' house, saying this will prove what she saw was real. By chance, as she is driving, she sees the fleeing Vincent, whom she joins, and the two of them come upon a silo where there is some Invader-like electronic devices and a **glass aquarium tank full of butterflies who devour a piece of meat** like piranha fish. Returning to town, a somewhat foolish move, Vincent narrowly misses getting caught by Gabbard again. He makes his way to Ed's house as Ames and Miss Havergill (Jeanette Nolan), another old biddy who wants Ellen to keep her mouth shut, get ready to take Ellen to the funny farm in a nearby community after chloroforming her. Ed, who has been denied a final farewell with Ellen, returns home to find Vincent there. He still distrusts Vincent until he calls the phone operator to inquire about the sanitarium where Ellen is being taken, only to discover that there is no such place. The two of them then pursue Ellen to the farm where she saw the equipment at the beginning of the show and where she is going to be terminated. The farmer, Ira Danielson (William Challee) is shot dead and immolates, as does Gabbard, who is attacked by another bunch of **carnivorous butterflies**. Ames and Havergill rush to the silo where they blow it up with themselves in it, once again eliminating evidence of Invaders. When all the fuss has died down, Vincent wants Ellen and Ed to talk to the appropriate authorities about what happened, but they tell him they just want to keep quiet about everything and get on with their lives. Vincent says OK.

Found with a search for `"the invaders" "carnivorous butterflies"` after `"the invaders" "carnivorous moths"` failed.

Comment: Yes. How silly that I was fixated on moths -- it is more poetic to use butterflies.

Comment: I like the website -- covers such trivia as points in show where Vincent smokes. How weird that 1967 is more than 50 years ago; how did that happen??

Comment: Not that it matters to the fantasy, but butterflies are not capable of ingesting anything but liquids; their mouthparts are like straws. That said, many species do enjoy sipping the fluids from dead animals as a break from the usual diet of nectar, fruit juices, and tree sap.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron:  But there are insects that bite that perhaps could be dangerous from the physical biting, not venom or disease: I believe locust actually bit people although I do not know whether a human could actually be injured by even a large "flock" of them.

Comment: Oh assuredly, and in fiction you can stretch reality anyhow. According to this source, swarming locusts don't bite people, though they may pinch them, and locusts can eat the clothing off of people. https://www.republicworld.com/india-news/education/do-locusts-bite-humans-are-locust-swarms-dangerous-harmful.html

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: Locusts will eat each other sometime but human skin may be too tough for them. Perhaps a huge swarm all pinching a human could eventually do damage -- not fun for a human, although no doubt quite exciting for the locusts.